# Cloud SQL Postgres No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://google/

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Thanks in advance!

I am new to gcp and am trying to use Cloud SQL Postgres.
I have a database that is created and would want to create/update/delete tables into it using either java or scala.

I am trying to use postgres-socket-factory from 'com.google.cloud.sql' package.
But while creating a connection I get an error that

```
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://google/"
```

Here is my code

```
def getConnection(url:String) : Connection = {
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
  import java.sql.DriverManager
  DriverManager.getConnection(url)
}
```

What is the means for Java/Scala clients to access db from Cloud SQL?

Yes after following instructions from comments and changing the url it worked but fails with

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:600)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:147)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:598)
    ... 15 more
```

How to address this failure?

Regards,

Comment: It should be `jdbc:postgresql://`

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app#java , Cloud SQL API enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Most libraries on GCP use the [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) (ADC) strategy for handling credentials. The [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#authentication) for this project mentions this library does as well. The Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory uses these credentials to authenticate the connections against your database.

The quickest way is to use `gcloud auth application-default login`, which will set your personal credentials as the default. However, the safest and most secure way is to create a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) for the application, grant it the "Cloud SQL Client" IAM role, and use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to pass the location of the service account key to the library.