# Can't build docker image for google app engine because exception is thrown during hikaripool initialization

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

"Etwas Ungewöhnliches ist passiert, das den Treiber fehlschlagen ließ. Bitte teilen Sie diesen Fehler mit."

This means:

Something unusual happened that caused the driver to fail. Please report this error.

I am able to connect to the database from console on my local machine, by logging in, authenticating and listing my existing database.

First i thought maybe it's because of the missing credentials json file. But i still get the error (at the end of this post)

The application.properties file

```
spring.profiles.active=postgresql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath*:sql/data.sql
# JPA
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
# JWT
jwt.secret=mart11
# Server
server.port=${port:8080}
# Postgre
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.sql.init.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.data=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
```

and the application-postgresql.properties file:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=mart11
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=mart11-reservation:europe-west1:mart11
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=cloud-key/mart11-reservation-bb76b28dff7c.json
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Etwas Ungewöhnliches ist passiert, das den Treiber fehlschlagen ließ. Bitte teilen Sie diesen Fehler mit.
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Etwas Ungewöhnliches ist passiert, das den Treiber fehlschlagen ließ. Bitte teilen Sie diesen Fehler mit.
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Etwas Ungewöhnliches ist passiert, das den Treiber fehlschlagen ließ. Bitte teilen Sie diesen Fehler mit.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Etwas Ungewöhnliches ist passiert, das den Treiber fehlschlagen ließ. Bitte teilen Sie diesen Fehler mit.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Comment: @llic Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows that the Default Credentials are not available so it will be difficult for Application Default Credentials(ADC)  to authenticate the service account because GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not set.

You can follow the [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373735/cloud-sql-postgres-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcpostgres-google) where a Googler has provided a relevant answer regarding the Application Default Credentials exception you are facing.